# Convert Python datetime to rfc 2822

Tags: python, datetime, rfc2822

I want to convert a Python datetime to an RFC 2822 datetime.  I've tried these methods to no avail:

```
>>> from email.Utils import formatdate
>>> import datetime
>>> formatdate(datetime.datetime.now())
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/email    /utils.py", line 159, in formatdate
    now = time.gmtime(timeval)
TypeError: a float is required
```

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Here's some working code, broken down into simple pieces just for clarity:

```
>>> import datetime
>>> import time
>>> from email import utils
>>> nowdt = datetime.datetime.now()
>>> nowtuple = nowdt.timetuple()
>>> nowtimestamp = time.mktime(nowtuple)
>>> utils.formatdate(nowtimestamp)
'Tue, 10 Aug 2010 20:43:53 -0000'
```

Explanation: `email.utils.formatdate` wants a timestamp -- i.e., a float with seconds (and fraction thereof) since the epoch.  A `datetime` instance doesn't give you a timestamp directly -- but, it *can* give you a time-tuple with the `timetuple` method, and `time.mktime` of course can then make a timestamp from such a tuple.

EDIT: In Python 3.3 and newer you can do the same in less steps:

```
>>> import datetime
>>> from email import utils
>>> nowdt = datetime.datetime.now()
>>> utils.format_datetime(nowdt)
'Tue, 10 Feb 2020 10:06:53 -0000'
```

See `format_datetime` [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/email.utils.html#email.utils.format_datetime) for details on usage.

Comment: why not just use time.time() ?

Comment: In version 3.3 `datetime` has got the `timestamp` method, making this process much quicker.

Comment: in Python 3.3 email.utils got method `format_datetime()` which simplifies this process: https://docs.python.org/3/library/email.utils.html#email.utils.format_datetime

Answer (score 27):

If you indeed want the current time, just call `formatdate` with no arguments:

```
>>> from email.utils import formatdate
>>> formatdate()
'Tue, 10 Aug 2010 20:40:23 -0000'
```

But, if you must pass it an argument, you want the output of `time.time` (a number of seconds since 01/01/1970):

```
>>> import time
>>> formatdate(time.time())
'Tue, 10 Aug 2010 20:41:43 -0000'
```

FWIW, `datetime.datetime.now()` returns a `datetime` object, which is not what `formatdate` expects.

Edited to add: if you already have a datetime object, you can format it appropriately for formatdate:

```
>>> import datetime
>>> dt = datetime.datetime.now()
>>> formatdate(float(dt.strftime('%s')))
'Tue, 10 Aug 2010 20:46:16 -0000'
```

Edited: Alex Martelli noted that the '%s' format string for strftime may not be portable across platforms. A possible alternative would be, as he himself suggested,

```
>>> formatdate(time.mktime(dt.timetuple()))
'Tue, 10 Aug 2010 20:46:16 -0000'
```

Comment: Interesting -- the `'%s'` format to `strftime` appears to be undocumented, and thus one of those which "happen to work on some platforms" (but not on all of them) -- unless you have docs that show it _will_ work cross-platform?

Comment: Actually, that's the format string that the Unix "date" command takes to output epoch-based time, I used it without thinking and it worked :) I'll check and get back to you (or change my answer).

Comment: Well, http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior states that "The full set of format codes supported varies across platforms, because Python calls the platform C library’s strftime() function, and platform variations are common." And, on Linux, man 3 strftime lists '%s' as a possible format value. So I suppose you're right, it's likely not to be portable. Thanks :)

Comment: It's not portable - on Windows (Python 2.7) `'%s'`doesn't work: `ValueError: Invalid format string`

Comment: @theta did you read my full answer? The last paragraph and code block address exactly that.

Comment: Yeah I know, but as no one confirmed, I did note that on Windows `'%s'`doesn't work ;)

Answer (score 11):

Python 3.3, in addition to the methods mentioned by other commenters, also added a `format_datetime` method, which is much cleaner:

```
>>> import datetime
>>> import email.utils
>>> dt = datetime.datetime.now()
>>> email.utils.format_datetime(dt)
'Thu, 09 Mar 2017 10:50:00 -0000'
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple method using strftime. Python 2.7. Note: timezone = EST

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> my_date = datetime.now()
>>> my_date.strftime('%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S -0500')
'Wed, 22 Apr 2020 10:52:11 -0500'
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're using this for e.g. a HTTP header, and want `GMT` rather than `-0000`:

- From a `datetime`, use `format_datetime` (emphasis mine):

  > **If it is an aware timezone with offset zero**, then *usegmt* may be set to
  > `True`, in which case the string `GMT` is used instead of the numeric
  > timezone offset.

  ```
  >>> from datetime import datetime, timezone
  >>> from email.utils import format_datetime
  >>> format_datetime(datetime.now(timezone.utc), usegmt=True)
  'Wed, 27 Oct 2021 11:00:46 GMT'
  ```
- From a timestamp, use `formatdate`:

  > Optional *usegmt* is a flag that when `True`, outputs a date string
  > with the timezone as an ascii string `GMT`, rather than a numeric
  > `-0000`... This only applies when *localtime* is `False`.

  ```
  >>> from email.utils import formatdate
  >>> from time import time
  >>> formatdate(time(), usegmt=True)
  'Wed, 27 Oct 2021 11:05:29 GMT'
  ```